# Entity Framework Code First and Connection String Issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, connection-string

I am getting this error when using Entity Framework 4.1 code first.  I can not find any sources of what exactly to use.

```
Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

<add name="DataContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/GrassrootsHoopsDataContext.csdl|res://*/GrassrootsHoopsDataContext.ssdl|res://*/GrassrootsHoopsDataContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=myserver.com;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Btw I think this type of connectionstrings with "metadata.." is only for model first and database first

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For EF Code First you can use ordinary connection string if you are using `SQL Server`.

```
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="Data Source=myserver.com;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thanks, finally a correct answer. I only wasted the better part of the day trying the find or generate the metadata files ...

Comment: Thank you.  I had the same issue, but I also had to correct the `ConnectionString` I was dynamically building and passing into the `DbContext` via the controller's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating dynamic connection string for Code First Entity Framework than you can do using only Sql Connection String Builder as given below.

```
 public static string  DynamicConnectionString(SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder)
 {
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = "ServerName";
    builder.InitialCatalog = "DatabaseName";
    builder.UserID = "UserId";
    builder.Password = "Password";
    builder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
    builder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;    
    return builder.ConnectionString.ToString();
}
```