# Passing ConnectionString for Entity constructor must include provider="System.Data.SqlClient" & providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, connection-string, dbcontext, entities

I need to pass a the connection string to an Entity object constructor (cannot be stored in config).

I have successfully used the EntityConnectionStringBuilder to connect to the database but believe because it does not allow me to add `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` (only the provider property > `provider="System.Data.SqlClient`") will not let me update the database.

How can this be passed to the constructor along with the connection string from the string builder.

My connection string is basically identical to this

```
connectionString="metadata=.\AdventureWorks.csdl|.\AdventureWorks.ssdl|.\AdventureWorks.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=localhost;
         Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=60;
         multipleactiveresultsets=true'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set the outer `providerName` - you just need to replicate the `connectionString` entry from your web.config.

```
var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
...

var entBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
entBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
entBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
entBuilder.Metadata = "res://...";

using ( var db = new AdventureWorksContext( entBuilder.ConnectionString ) )
{
  ...
```

---

Also, your `metadata` configuration looks odd. I have always used this format:

```
metadata=res://*/AdventureWorks.csdl|res://*/AdventureWorks.ssdl|res://*/AdventureWorks.msl;
```

---

If you're using Code First, you just need the SQL Connection String.

See this question: [Entity Framework Code First and Connection String Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135600/entity-framework-code-first-and-connection-string-issue)